# How to read a gzipped tar archive to `Vec<u8>` without decompressing it?

Tags: rust, compression, gzip, tar

I'm trying to upload a byte vector to cloud storage.

This byte vector should be a compressed archive. To achieve this I need to obtain a `Vec<u8>` by reading the compressed archive which I have created. I know that gzipped files do not contain their size and when I try to read it normally I don't get all the bytes.

It seems that it only reads the header because the resulting vector is 10 bytes.

### Example

```rust
use std::io::Read;
    
fn main() {
    
    // Creates the archive and compresses it.
    let file = std::fs::File::create("example.tar.gz").unwrap();
    let encoder = flate2::write::GzEncoder::new(file, flate2::Compression::default());
    let mut archive = tar::Builder::new(encoder);
    archive.append_dir_all("example_dir", "path/to/example_dir").unwrap();
    archive.finish().unwrap();

    // I see that this does not work since it reads a wrong length.
    // But I don't know how to achive it.
    let example_bytes : Vec<u8> = std::fs::read("example.tar.gz").unwrap();
    dbg!(example_bytes.len());
    
    // Corrupt
    std::fs::write("rewritten.tar.gz", example_bytes).unwrap();
}
```

If I try with `BufReader`,

```rust
    let file = File::open("example.tar.gz").unwrap();
    let mut file = std::io::BufReader::new(file);
    let mut bytes = Vec::new();
    file.rewind().unwrap();
    file.read_to_end(&mut bytes).unwrap();
    // Corrupt
    // The resulting file is not 10 bytes this time but,
    // 392 bytes less than the original amount. 
    // The corrupt file ends with the sequence 
    // FF D3 E5 FF 3B F6 5F A3 F8 if it means something.
    std::fs::write("rewritten.tar.gz", bytes).unwrap();
```

Is there a way to get the raw bytes of this compressed archive so I can upload it to cloud storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> archive.finish().unwrap();
> ```

That is not sufficient:

> This function should only be called when the archive has been written entirely **and if an I/O error happens the underlying object still needs to be acquired**.

All `finish` does is write out two empty records (which signals the end of archive) and then set the `finished` flag on the `Builder`.

You need to call `into_inner` to [`finish()`](https://docs.rs/flate2/latest/flate2/write/struct.GzEncoder.html#method.finish) the gzip archive, following which you need to flush / close the file itself.

In fact calling `tar::Builder::finish` is unnecessary since `tar::Builder::into_inner` does that for you if the archive is not yet finish-ed.

Comment: YW. I've got to say that's not a great interface for `tar::Builder`, it is quite error-prone.